# Reducing 1001 queries into 2 in Ruby on Rails -- but can't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

You know sometimes you have 1000 records of Foo, and each one needs to access `foo.bar`, where `bar` is another model, then there will be 1000 queries more...

I thought the following line, for 1000 records,

```
@foos = Foo.find(:all, :include => :bar)
```

used to make this into 1 query in some early version of Rails (by table join), but I don't know why the Rails 2 Foundation book says it is further optimized into 2 queries (why 2 queries is better than 1?):

```
SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos"
SELECT "bars".* FROM "bars" WHERE ("bars"."name" IN ('0001','0002', ... ))
```

but I don't know why in the view, when I print out `foo.bar.title`, it will still invoke 1 query per row as seen on the console log, so making it 1002 queries still.  I thought somehow it should be 2 queries and that's it?

Comment: Is title an attribute in the bars table? And can you please include the code surrounding foo.bar.title? What kind of loop are you using?

Comment: yes, title is an attribute of bar...  the loop is merely a  `@foos.each do |foo|`, it shouldn't?

Comment: The one part of your query that looks a litte odd is that you are querying bars.name instead of an integer id field. Do you have some kind of special primary key setup?

Comment: yes, it has the association of using `name` as the foreign key

Comment: As per the two queries instead of one I think the principle is that two selects each on one table are faster than a join query on two tables. The 1002 queries are strange indeed can you post something of your log please?

Comment: Can you please include your model code where you define the has_many or has_one association? The two queries are executed because you need to get the foo data and one to get the related bar data. You won't be able to do better that two queries, but you shouldn't have 1002.

Answer (score 0):

That looks wierd...

```
@foos = Foo.find(:all, :include => :bar)
```

then your code should be:

```
@foos.each do |foo|
  foo.bar.title
end
```

First law of demeter says you should have a method called bar_title in your foo class

```
@foos.each do |foo|
  foo.bar_title
end
```

Last please post a couple of the queries you see in the console.  that is the hint that will solve why this is happening.

Comment: right, my code is `foo.bar.title`, what is `foo.bar_title` because that gives an error if I try it.  The query is really simple, merely,   `Bar Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "bars".* FROM "bars" WHERE "bars"."name" = '0001' LIMIT 1` (and there are 1000+ of them).  Note that it is quite fast, only 0.1 or 0.2ms... so the whole page is rendered in 0.4 seconds for 1200 records.